# Change a Background-Image Url to an Input Field's value

Tags: jquery, css, click, attr

I have an input element, a span, and a div with a background image property.

```
<span>Go</span><input id="ImageUrl"/>

<div id="Image"></div>
```

I'm trying to create a script where if a user pastes/types a link into the input field, then clicks the Go button, the background image property for the div changes to that url.

Comment: #Jason you got the answer, please make response for it. you can make accept, upvote or just comment in their answer :)

Comment: @bungdito - if you're referring to my previous thread asking the same question, things changed, and there was clarity issues in that one. I didn't want to re-edit the whole question. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In < head> :

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
    function show() {
        $('#Image').css('background-image', 'url("' + $('#ImageUrl').val() + '")');
    }
</script>
```

In < body> :

```
<span>Go</span><input id="ImageUrl"  /> <!-- the textbox can get the user input Url of Image-->
<div id="Image" style="width:200px; height:200px;"></div> <!-- the div which show Image -->
<input type="button" value="Go" onclick="show()" /> <!-- the GO button -->
```

If you have problems please let me know :)

Comment: i changed it to a click function as that suits me better, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Based on your markup, if you give the `<span>` an `id` of `Btn` (for the sake of specificity), the following would work:

```
$("#Btn").click(function(){
    $("#Image").css("backgroundImage", "url('"+$("#ImageUrl").val()+"')");
});
```

**Demo: [jsfiddle.net/mSAsU](http://jsfiddle.net/Marcel/mSAsU/)**

Answer (score 0):

well basicly you can:

```
$('input[type=submit]').click(function(){
    // for example changing it by appending "a"
    $("#ImageUrl").val($("#ImageUrl").val() + 'a';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work nicely. Note you have to include the `url()` part in the CSS function call.

```
$("#ImageUrl").blur(function(){
    $("#Image").css("background-image", "url("+$(this).val()+")");
});
```